# Why CakePHP Bootstrap files in 'app/webroot' is not loaded from add.ctp file?

Tags: cakephp

In my CakePHP project I've put all my css and js files in 'app/webroot' folder and index.ctp is loaded with all designs. But add.ctp and edit.ctp files are load without css/js files in '../webroot'.

```
$this->layout = 'newlayout';
```

I put this code in my andex(), add() and edit() action in 'controller' file.

My newlayout.ctp file code is

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <title><?php echo $title_for_layout; ?></title>
    <!-- Tell the browser to be responsive to screen width -->
    <meta content='width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no' name='viewport'>
    <!-- Bootstrap 3.3.4 -->
    <link href="bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />    
    <!-- FontAwesome 4.3.0 -->
    <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.3.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <!-- Ionicons 2.0.0 -->
    <link href="https://code.ionicframework.com/ionicons/2.0.1/css/ionicons.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />    
    <!-- Theme style -->
    <link href="dist/css/AdminLTE.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <!-- AdminLTE Skins. Choose a skin from the css/skins 
         folder instead of downloading all of them to reduce the load. -->
    <link href="dist/css/skins/_all-skins.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <!-- iCheck -->
    <link href="plugins/iCheck/flat/blue.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <!-- Morris chart -->
    <link href="plugins/morris/morris.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <!-- jvectormap -->
    <link href="plugins/jvectormap/jquery-jvectormap-1.2.2.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <!-- Date Picker -->
    <link href="plugins/datepicker/datepicker3.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <!-- Daterange picker -->
    <link href="plugins/daterangepicker/daterangepicker-bs3.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <!-- bootstrap wysihtml5 - text editor -->
    <link href="plugins/bootstrap-wysihtml5/bootstrap3-wysihtml5.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

    <!-- HTML5 Shim and Respond.js IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
    <!-- WARNING: Respond.js doesn't work if you view the page via file:// -->
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
        <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/html5shiv/3.7.2/html5shiv.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/respond/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->
  </head>
  <body class="skin-blue sidebar-mini">
    <div class="wrapper">

      <header class="main-header">
        <!-- Logo -->
        <a href="#" class="logo">
          <!-- mini logo for sidebar mini 50x50 pixels -->

          <!-- logo for regular state and mobile devices -->
          <span class="logo-lg"><b>POS</b> App</span>
        </a>
        <!-- Header Navbar: style can be found in header.less -->
        <nav class="navbar navbar-static-top" role="navigation">
          <!-- Sidebar toggle button-->
          <a href="#" class="sidebar-toggle" data-toggle="offcanvas" role="button">
            <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
          </a>
          <div class="navbar-custom-menu">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
              <!-- Messages: style can be found in dropdown.less-->

              <!-- Notifications: style can be found in dropdown.less -->

              <!-- Tasks: style can be found in dropdown.less -->

              <!-- User Account: style can be found in dropdown.less -->

              <!-- Control Sidebar Toggle Button -->

            </ul>
          </div>
        </nav>
      </header>
      <!-- Left side column. contains the logo and sidebar -->
      <aside class="main-sidebar">
        <!-- sidebar: style can be found in sidebar.less -->
        <section class="sidebar">
          <!-- Sidebar user panel -->
          <div class="user-panel">

          </div>

          <!-- sidebar menu: : style can be found in sidebar.less -->

        </section>
        <!-- /.sidebar -->
      </aside>

      <!-- Content Wrapper. Contains page content -->
      <div class="content-wrapper">
        <!-- Content Header (Page header) -->
        <section class="content-header">
          <h1>
            <?php echo $this->Session->flash(); ?>
          </h1>
          <ol class="breadcrumb">
            <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-dashboard"></i> Home</a></li>
            <li class="active">Dashboard</li>
          </ol>
        </section>

        <!-- Main content -->
        <section class="content">

            <?php echo $this->fetch('content'); ?>

          </section><!-- /.content -->
      </div><!-- /.content-wrapper -->
      <footer class="main-footer">
        <strong>Copyright &copy; 2014-2015 .</strong> All rights reserved.
      </footer>

      <!-- Control Sidebar -->      

      <div class='control-sidebar-bg'></div>
    </div><!-- ./wrapper -->

    <!-- jQuery 2.1.4 -->
    <script src="plugins/jQuery/jQuery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>
    <!-- jQuery UI 1.11.4 -->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <!-- Resolve conflict in jQuery UI tooltip with Bootstrap tooltip -->
    <script>
      $.widget.bridge('uibutton', $.ui.button);
    </script>
    <!-- Bootstrap 3.3.2 JS -->
    <script src="bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>    
    <!-- Morris.js charts -->
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/raphael/2.1.0/raphael-min.js"></script>
    <script src="plugins/morris/morris.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <!-- Sparkline -->
    <script src="plugins/sparkline/jquery.sparkline.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <!-- jvectormap -->
    <script src="plugins/jvectormap/jquery-jvectormap-1.2.2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="plugins/jvectormap/jquery-jvectormap-world-mill-en.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <!-- jQuery Knob Chart -->
    <script src="plugins/knob/jquery.knob.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <!-- daterangepicker -->
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.10.2/moment.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="plugins/daterangepicker/daterangepicker.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <!-- datepicker -->
    <script src="plugins/datepicker/bootstrap-datepicker.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <!-- Bootstrap WYSIHTML5 -->
    <script src="plugins/bootstrap-wysihtml5/bootstrap3-wysihtml5.all.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <!-- Slimscroll -->
    <script src="plugins/slimScroll/jquery.slimscroll.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <!-- FastClick -->
    <script src='plugins/fastclick/fastclick.min.js'></script>
    <!-- AdminLTE App -->
    <script src="dist/js/app.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>    

    <!-- AdminLTE dashboard demo (This is only for demo purposes) -->
    <script src="dist/js/pages/dashboard.js" type="text/javascript"></script>    

    <!-- AdminLTE for demo purposes -->
    <script src="dist/js/demo.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

I've checked the request response for 'add' pageload and i got this response -

```
 The action bootstrap is not defined in controller
```

and each request for css and js file got this kind of error response!
I've no clue!

Comment: Share the code of  `newlayout`  layout where you call the css & js files.

Comment: Please check I've shared the code of 'newlayout.ctp' file @u2460470

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should use `CakePHP Helper` to include assets file(css, js etc). Let's see how to use include css files?

```
<head>
   <?php echo $this->Html->css(array('forms', 'tables', 'menu')); ?>

  // forms, tables, menu are the css file thoese are locate under app/webroot/css directory
</head>
```

Look [HtmlHelper::css on CakePHP 2.x](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/helpers/html.html#HtmlHelper::css)

Comment: I've edited my question after checking the response for 'css'/'js' files in browser when 'add' action is called. Please check. CakePHP is looking for action declaration for each 'folder' name!

Comment: With this approach the problem was solved. I was not in that project. And i recently know the status of that particular problem. Sorry for a real late. :)

Answer (score 0):

The error you have described,

```
The action bootstrap is not defined in controller
```

...is telling you that the action/route you are attempting to load, `bootstrap()`, is not a function found in that controller.

---

The above issue is likely unrelated to loading bootstrap. Double-check the route/URL you are attempting to access. If it is `http://example.com/controller/bootstrap` then the function (action) `bootstrap()` must be defined in that controller.

Once that is dealt with, you can find a working example of using Twitter Bootstrap with CakePHP in the [source of this app](https://github.com/chrisvogt/stats/blob/develop/app/View/Layouts/offcanvas.ctp#L59) on GitHub, which powers [stats.chrisvogt.me](http://stats.chrisvogt.me).

In this example I am using a hosted version of Bootstrap, but in the line below it you'll find an extension called Jasny Bootstrap that is located in `./app/webroot/components/jasny-bootstrap/[...]jasny-bootstrap.min.css`.

Also, in case you don't want to repeatedly define `$this->layout` in each of those actions: you can define a default custom layout for *all* actions using `beforeFilter()` in the [AppController like so](https://github.com/chrisvogt/stats/blob/develop/app/Controller/AppController.php#L64), or you can do this in individual controllers if you wish.

---

While not required, I'm a fan of using [Bower](http://bower.io) to [manage my front-end components](https://github.com/chrisvogt/stats/blob/develop/bower.json#L26) (such as Bootstrap). Should you feel like looking into this, make sure to [define a custom install directory](https://github.com/chrisvogt/stats/blob/develop/.bowerrc) somewhere under `./webroot`.